# Getting "Does not have a matching glue code" error for empty fields using Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I'm new to Cucumber. I want to test two login scenarios:

1. With valid credentials where user should be able to login successfully
2. With empty username and password where the user should not be able to login

I have the following code for the above scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Test login with valid credentials
Given Open firefox and start application
When I enter "<username>" and "<password>"
Then User should be able to login successfully

Examples: 
  | username | password |
  | ro       | mech     |

Scenario Outline: Test login with empty credentials
Given Open firefox and start application
When I enter  "<username>" and "<password>" (this shows a warning)
Then User should be not able to login 

Examples: 
  | username | password |
  |          |          |
```

In the java file I have the following code:

```
@When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void I_enter_and_(String username, String password) throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("ember629")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("ember640")).sendKeys(password);

}
```

My question is scenario 2 shows a warning message:

```
Step 'I enter  "<username>" and "<password>"' does not have a matching glue code
```

Does this mean that for every scenario like valid, empty and invalid credentials I need to write a separate java function? Can't I use the same java function:

```
public void I_enter_and_(String username, String password)
```

for all the scenarios? If I run the feature file I get this output:

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@When("^I enter  \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_enter_and(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Is there any way to reuse the java function `I_enter_and_`?

Comment: What class are you using to run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if that's an actual copy/paste of your error, it looks like you have an extra space after `I enter` in your step. To be sure, just copy the automatically suggested step and use it instead of the current one.

Another thing is that tat does not make sense to use `Scenario Outline` if you do not provide more than one example. It should look more like:

```
Scenario Outline: Test login with valid credentials
  Given Open firefox and start application
  When I enter "<username>" and "<password>"
  Then User "<maybe>" be able to login successfully

  Examples: 
    | username | password | maybe     | 
    | ro       | mech     | shall     | 
    |          |          | shall not |
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that , you can use may be and give multiple output. I had many examples but just for simplicity of the question I deleted those.

Comment: @Ram There are different ways to make the feature files more readable and helpful. Maybe you should go through some tutorial. BTW, did adding space fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Glue path would be correct and match with stepdef path as follows:

[image]